# Firebase Storage Rules with Custom Claims

Tags: python, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-storage, firebase-security

I am unable to get Firebase Storage work with custom rules and using custom claims.

In my Python Admin panel, I do the following to create the user and assign a claim client_id:

```
# Standard Auth
import firebase_admin
from firebase_admin import db, storage, auth
cred   = firebase_admin.credentials.Certificate('path_to_cert_json')
app    = firebase_admin.initialize_app(cred, 'config')
bucket = storage.bucket(app=app)

# Create User
auth.create_user(email=email) 

# Create custom claims
auth.set_custom_user_claims(uid, {'client_id': client_id})
```

Then for Firebase rules, I try to allow the user to only read (or download) files when the file is in a subfolder with the client_id:

*File structure on storage:*

```
/{environment}/{client_id}/other_folders_and_files
```

I set the following storage rules:

```
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    match /{environment}/{client_id}/{allPaths=**} {
      allow read: if request.auth.token.client_id == client_id
    }
  }
}
```

But that gives me an error that Permission is denied.

What am I doing wrong?

Note:

- client_id is correct and the folder structure is correct, have checked this a million times.

Comment: I'm about to try this too. Seems like the only possible solution!

Comment: Did you solve it?

Comment: Can you please look at this [git](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-admin-python/blob/4d01830df04cb8b5b1870915ed01d0159faee2d5/snippets/auth/index.py#L243-L265), maybe this can solve your question

Comment: I have solved part of it: by creating custom claims using the Admin SDK (CLI on my system), I can check them in the storage rules. That part works. I haven't yet written the part to create a server-side function that triggers on updates to the user record in Firestore and creates/updates the custom auth claims, but will do that today. Assuming that works, it seems to be the only (albeit very circuitous and time-consuming and hard-to-test) route. Would be so much easier if storage rules could just read Firestore records. Now I have to keep everything in two places using server-side functions.

Comment: After a few hours work I can say yes, this definitely works. I wrote a cloud function triggered by a change to any doc in `users/{userId}` that syncs the customClaims from the db.

Comment: Why do you need to have a function to sync the claims at all time, cant you just set the claim once upon user creation as I do in my question?

Comment: Are you sure that the claim was applied to the user? You can [check claims client-side](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/custom-claims#propagate_custom_claims_to_the_client), which I would suggest just to verify that the claim was properly applied. Also, in the line `auth.set_custom_user_claims(uid, {'client_id': client_id})`, where does the value of `uid` come from? Can you update your code to include that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If I'm not wrong you are using this wrong. Should be:

```
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    match /{environment}/{client_id}/{allPaths=**} {
      allow read: if request.auth.uid == client_id
    }
  }
}
```

The token returns others objects, like:

- email
- email_verified
- phone_number
- name
- sub

So for you be able to compare the user Id you must use `request.auth.uid`. This way will compare the cliente client id. If you want to take a look at the [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.firestore.Request#auth), is everything abour the `request.auth`.

## Edit

Case you want your own custom token, like: `request.auth.token.client_id`, you need do that with this code in Python:

```
uid = 'some-uid'
additional_claims = {
    'client_id': your_custom_client_id
}

custom_token = auth.create_custom_token(uid, additional_claims)
```

Then you can use in your storage rules:

```
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    match /{environment}/{client_id}/{allPaths=**} {
      allow read: if request.auth.token.client_id == client_id
    }
  }
}
```

See the [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/create-custom-tokens)

Comment: This is not right. UID is an unique ID assigned by Firebase by default. Client_ID is a custom claim that I assigned to the user with an UID. I do not want to set UID=Client_ID, they are two different things.

Comment: I see... But `request.auth.token` do not have a `client_id` property. You should create your own custom token. Take a look at the [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/create-custom-tokens). You can see how do that. Case you already have done that your code is right.

Comment: Ok.. but there must be a way to get the custom claim in the request.auth, which is what I am looking for. See the part: `If the custom token contains additional claims, they can be referenced off of the auth.token (Firebase Realtime Database) or request.auth.token (Cloud Storage) object in your rules...` and select "Storage Rules"

Comment: And your answer is exactly what I have in my question, no? Where is the difference?

Comment: That's true haha... My bad I did not see the custom part, down there....

Comment: The docs are terrible -- they don't address how to authenticate vs. any group at all. Only by individual user. The answer seems to be server-side functions to set custom auth claims but the doc never gets into that.

Answer (score 2):

Custom claims are the only way to do this right now.
Rules should look like this:

```
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    function isAuth() {
      return request.auth != null && request.auth.uid != null
    }
    function isAdmin() {
      return isAuth() &&
      request.auth.token.admin == true;
    }
    function clientMatch(clientId) { // expects users "client" field to be ID of client
      return isAuth() &&
      clientId == request.auth.token.clientId;
    }
    match /storage/path/{clientId}/{allPaths=**} {
        allow read, write: if isAdmin() || clientMatch(clientId)
    }
```

where we use two custom fields on the auth token: `admin` and `clientId`.
The cloud function to sync with the db can look something like this:

```js
exports.updateUser = functions.firestore
  .document('users/{userId}')
  .onWrite( async (change, context) => {
    // change.before and change.after are DocumentSnapshot objects
    const userid=context.params.userId // (from {userId} above)
    const isDeleted = !change.after.exists
    const isNew = !change.before.exists
    let customClaims = {}
    if (!isDeleted) {
      let newData = change.after.data()
      let oldData = change.before.data()
      // do we need to update anything?
      if (isNew ||
          newData.admin !== oldData.admin ||
          newData.client !== oldData.client) {
        customClaims.admin = Boolean(newData.admin)
        customClaims.clientId = newData.client
      }
    }
    else {
      let oldData = change.before.data()
      customClaims.admin = false
      customClaims.clientId = null
    }
    // now do the update if needed
    if (customClaims !== {}) {
      // See https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.auth.Auth
      await admin.auth().setCustomUserClaims(userid, customClaims)
      console.log(`Updating client for ${isNew?"new":"existing"} user ${userid}: ` +
                  `${JSON.stringify(customClaims)}`)
    }
  })
```

That runs on any change to the user document, and syncs it to the auth's custom claims.

Comment: when accessing tokens, I get `Property admin is undefined on object.`

Comment: ... It was because in the simulator - this user does not have any tokens, so the rule is an error which is equivalent to a `false` .. Same-same

Answer (score 0):

For completeness, one need to create a token before setting the token for the user.

Thus full code:

```
uid = 'some-uid'
additional_claims = {
    'client_id': your_custom_client_id
}

# First time, only once needed
custom_token = auth.create_custom_token(uid, additional_claims)

# Then
auth.set_custom_user_claims(uid, additional_claims )
```