# Using User Claims in Firebase Storage rules

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-storage, firebase-admin, firebase-security

Is it possible to use custom claims in Firebase Storage rules?
It looks like those values are not accessible from there.

Here's my rule:

```
match /b/{bucket}/o {    
  match /{userId}/files/{fileName} {
    allow read: if request.auth.token.admin == true;
  }
}
```

Those rules throw an error:

> Error: simulator.rules line [13], column [20]. Property admin is
>   undefined on object.

I previously set the userClaims this way:

```
await admin.auth().setCustomUserClaims(user.uid, {
        groupToken: 'abecadlo',
        admin: true
    });
```

Comment: Did you use the Firebase Storage Simulator on Firebase Console? The Firebase Storage Simulator on Firebase Console can't simulate using Custom Claims. Could you try test security rules using your app?

Comment: Yes - [it **is** possible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54901291/firebase-storage-rules-with-custom-claims). I'm not sure why you're getting that error - unless  you are using the simulator like zkohi asked.

Answer (score 3):

The following rule should take the warning away:

```
    match /b/{bucket}/o {    
      match /{userId}/files/{fileName} {
        allow read: if "admin" in request.auth.token && request.auth.token.admin == true;
      }
    }
```